# Visual Studio Code terminal is not displaying script failure error message,number of specs and script runtime in seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

While testing angularjs website using protractor in javascript, Below lines are not displaying if script is failing. Hence I am not able to find the reason of script failure, it was working previously. Please let me know if there is any setting for terminal to get script failure error message, Number of specs, and script run time.

Failures:

> Message: Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, xyz) Stack:
>   4 specs, 2 failures Finished in 39.887 seconds.

Note: I know the reason of script failure. I captured above error message from another VS Code setup by running same script. But I want to see same error in my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your conf.js file, inside export.config object,
check for these lines. These lines are responsible for showing an error message.

```
// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node. 
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true, 
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
```